# Change content layout based on menu hierarchy

Tags: theme-development

I've tried googling this one but I can't seem to find the right keywords.

What I'm trying to do is to have the content of a landing page flow exactly like the hierarchy of the navigation menu.

For example, if I had `Home Features Pricing Blog Contact` as my menu, I'd like the content block to be in that order (in the same page). If I changed my menu to something like `Home Blog Pricing Features Contact`, the content block layout should change dynamically in that order as well.

Is there a tutorial/plugin out there (or if someone could explain how it's done) to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: on your landing page, do you want the content to display blocks of content taken from "Home Features etc." or do you want that content to come from somewhere else?

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar coming from `Home Features etc` pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to grab the menu in question,

then go through the array of items to output the content

```
function output_landing_page_content(){
    //grab the menu items in order
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $your_menu_id, array( 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ):

        //get post id of linked page/post
        $postid = url_to_postid( $menu_item->url );
        $your_menu_linked_post = get_post( $postid );

        //format content
        $your_content = apply_filters('the_content', $your_menu_linked_post->post_content);

        //display each page/post content however you want (add in titles, author meta or whatever)
        echo $your_content;
        echo '<hr />';

    endforeach;

}
```

just place your function in the template for your landing page

Comment: I didn't know that function existed, thanks a lot!